What could go wrong? I removed BlockReentrancy() from ObservableCollection<T>'s OnCollectionChanged()
My current project revolves around reading, modifying and writing a byte collection. I'm observing changes to the collection by using an ObservableCollection<byte> and subscribing to its CollectionChanged event.
Now, when certain bytes change, I need to react to this change by updating some other bytes in the same collection. However, ObservableCollection<T> doesn't allow modifications to the collection during a CollectionChanged event by using the diposable returned by BlockReentrancy() in its OnCollectionChanged() method and calling CheckReentrancy() as guard statement in its modifying methods (Add(), Remove(), etc.). See code below, taken from Microsoft's reference source.
protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (CollectionChanged != null)
    {
        using (BlockReentrancy())
        {
            CollectionChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}

In my specific case, the only changes are NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace actions. I will never add, remove or move items. While discussing this with a colleague we came to the conclusion, that in this particular case, I can just bluntly ignore reentrancies. I then came up with this customized UnsafeObservableCollection<T> (the wording may be suboptimal, please have mercy).
public class UnsafeObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public UnsafeObservableCollection() { }

    public UnsafeObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection) { }

    public UnsafeObservableCollection(List<T> list) : base(list) { }

    public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler? CollectionChanged;

    // ignoring reentrancy, allowing for collection updates within a collection changed event
    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) => CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
}

I'm still unsure as to what the implications could be, even if I'm "just" replacing items. Could I run into inconsistent state, an infinite update loop, or similar problems?
Am I about to do something stupid, or is this reasonable, given my specific context?
I hope someone can help me gain a better understanding and/or tell me if I'm missing a scenario in which this would break. Cheers

(afaik) The CollectionChanged event is meant to be used in UI (in combination with binding). UI-Components subscribes to this event to "know" when to update itself. For example a ListBox/ListView uses this to reinvalidate the contents and rebuild the items.

I think your derived class works fine. For extra safety, you may want to call base method for some cases while changing behavior for others where you want reentrancy. However, do note that it may now become recursive.

@TanveerBadar The problem is not recursion. The problem is that without blocking reentrancy all pending event listeners will get notified with outdated and invalid event data when a previous listener has modified the collection. This puts the application into an unpredictable state. That's why modifying the collection from the CollectionChanged event handler will throw an InvalidOperationException. It's similar to modifying the collection from a foreach (i.e. while using the collection's Enumerator).

You are risking your program crashing with this website's name.  Happens when the CollectionChanged event handler changes the collection again, which fires the CollectionChanged event which changes the collection again, which ..., etc.  WPF has to protect itself against that mishap since it has no idea what the event handler might do.  You do.

The reentrancy block is a safeguard. Like any safeguard it's not always needed in 100% of cases. This one protects against both stack overflows as Hans said and incorrect information going out to subscribers as BionicCode said. It also protects you during iterations of the collection. It's possible none of those things is going to be an issue in your use case. It's hard to know without seeing your entire app. I'd say in the abstract it's perfectly reasonable to ask the question and try your solution. Just test, test, test!

The question is, why would you notify listeners about changes and allow the reported changes to be invalid and outdated? Outdated because while notifying the listeners the collection has changed again? The event args provide very specific information about the change, like the changed items and their index. It can put your application in an unpredictable state.
A replace action is not less harmful. Technically a replace is a remove action followed by an add action. Just to emphasize how impactful a replace is. In a replace scenario, the new item might be already replaced with another item when a pending event listener is invoked. Blocking reentrancy prevents this from happening.
For example, when there are three participants: the collection owner and two observers.

Now the owner replaces the item at index 1 with a new item and then notifies the two other observers about the change.
Observer #1 is the first to get notified. The event args report a change at index 1. Observer #1 removes this item (or replaces it, the kind of action doesn't matter). At this point Observer #2 is still waiting for the original notification.
Now Observer #2 gets notified - still about the first change. The reported change index is 1, but the item is already gone (removed or replaced). Observer #2 missed that change. He lost track of the changes. We can imagine endless scenarios where this will introduce a bug.

For example, Observer #2 wants to inspect every new item because he waits for a particular item to appear.
If Observer #2 implements undo/redo the history would be broken leading to the loss of data for the user.
Or even worse, the removed item at index 1 was the last item in the collection. When Observer #2 uses the reported index to access the collection it will throw an IndexOutOfRangeException.
Like modifying a collection while it is being enumerated is not allowed (for the same reasons), modifying a collection from an event handler is also forbidden.
I don't think that an observable object, like an UnsafeObservableCollection, that loses control over the event related state and therefore notifies observers with invalid event data is of any good.
If there are more than a single observer, modifying the ObservableCollection will cause it to throw a InvalidOperationException exception.
As soon there are two or more observers the notifications of the collection would become dangerous as they potentially introduce an unpredictable state to the application - hence the exception to force the application to halt.
The conclusion is that if you can guarantee that there will be a single listener during the lifetime of the collection or that no listener will depend on the event data you could probably avoid blocking reentrancy.
Be aware that in a binding context or ItemsControl context you already have at least two observers that heavily depend on change details: the binding engine (to forward the changes to the collection view) and the ItemsControl that also tracks changes to manage its item containers.
And don't forget to call CheckReentrancy from the methods that modify the collection, in case you keep the reentrancy blocking behavior.
Calling BlockReentrancy is pointless if your mutating methods don't call CheckReentrancy. They go in tandem, otherwise blocking reentrancy won't work.
A good way to implement a stable and reliable ObservableCollection is to use the overrides correctly:
public class SafeCustomObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{    
  // Constructors ...


  // Honor the dangers of reentrancy for the collection's client code.
  // ObservableCollection only allows reentrancy when there is a single observer.
  protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) 
  {
    // Some additional behavior

    // Delegate reentrancy control to the base class 
    // by invoking the CollectionChanged event via the existing base members.
    base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
  }

  // Example override of a modifying method
  protected override void SetItem(int index, T item)
  {
    // Implement some extended behavior (do not change the state)

    // Delegate reentrancy control to base class
    base.SetItem(index, item);
  }

  // If you completely override the behavior of ObservableCollection 
  // e.g. the way items are stored and managed, 
  // you must ensure a predictable state by invoking the 
  // protected base members for this purpose
  protected override void SetItem(int index, T item)
  {
    // Delegate reentrancy control to the base class.
    // Will throw if there is an incomplete notification procedure ongoing.
    CheckReentrancy();

    // Implement and override behavior
  }
}

